# Pandas - Compare cell to cell in same column x rows ahead

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am seeking to compare 2 values in the same dataframe series that are in different rows, and then in a new column save the outcome of the comparison with a numpy where statement. For example, this seems like it should work, but the outcome is funky.

```
periods_to_process = [1, 2, 3]
for period in periods_to_process:
    df[f'its_greater_{period}_rows_in_the_future'] = np.where(df['column1'].shift(period) > df['column1'], True, False)
```

Here's a dataframe of the output. The 'column1' in the dataframe is identical to the input column. The goal is to determine if a value in a row is less than a value in the same column in the future.  This was created with the above code snippet the question -- you can see most of the results are wrong.

```
column1 its_greater_1_rows_in_the_future
0.2997  FALSE
0.3036  FALSE
0.3186  FALSE
0.3214  FALSE
0.3108  TRUE
0.3164  FALSE
0.3192  FALSE
0.3153  TRUE
0.3237  FALSE
0.3209  TRUE
0.3136  TRUE
0.3131  TRUE
0.2852  TRUE
0.3047  FALSE
0.3214  FALSE
0.3008  TRUE
0.2924  TRUE
0.3013  FALSE
0.2863  TRUE
```

Am I doing anything obviously wrong? Thank you so much for your feedback.

Comment: "outcome is funky"? What's the output vs expected?

Comment: Uh, what's your question? How is the outcome 'funky'?

Comment: A sample of the DataFrame with expected output would be useful here.

Comment: Here's a dataframe of the output. The 'column1' in the dataframe is identical to the input column. The goal is to determine if a value in a row is less than a value in the same column in the future.  This was created with the above code snippet the question:    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Goo_0e62dwlfAAUi5tTEaWxKDxIPJXtS2D2ZefhWUC8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Future in the sense of what? Why do you say its wrong. Take some row and explain. Also put some desired output @cales.

Comment: I'm sorry for the dumb question. The first row in the above output column1 clearly is less than the value in the next row, but the result is False when it should be True, since the future row value of column1 is greater.

Answer (score 1):

use `shift(-1)` to compare the row with the next row in the future.

```
periods_to_process = [1, 2, 3]
for period in periods_to_process:
    df[f'its_greater_{period}_rows_in_the_future'] = df['column1'] < df['column1'].shift(-period)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct code:

```
row_periods_to_process = [1,2,3]
for period in row_periods_to_process:
    df[f'shifted_{period}_rows_value'] = df['column1'].shift(period*-1)
    df[f'future_{period}_rows_is_higher'] = np.where(df[f'shifted_{period}_rows_value'] > df['column1'], True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
    close1 = []
    close2 = []
    close3 = []

    index = df.shape[0]
    for i in range(index):
        if i+1 < index:
            if df['column1'].values[i] > df['column1'].values[i+1]:
                close1.append(True)
            else:
                close1.append(False)
        else:
            close1.append(False)

        if i + 2 < index:
            if df['column1'].values[i] > df['column1'].values[i+2]:
                close2.append(True)
            else:
                close2.append(False)
        else:
            close2.append(False)

        if i + 3 < index:
            if df['column1'].values[i] > df['column1'].values[i+3]:
                close3.append(True)
            else:
                close3.append(False)
        else:
            close3.append(False)

    df.insert(1, "close1", close1, True)
    df.insert(2, "close2", close2, True)
    df.insert(3, "close3", close3, True)

    print(df)
```

thats how i did it, i always create list of new answers and insert it as column into dataframe

Comment: you can replace np.where with my simple python condition